# Оптимизация по времени и памяти

Tags: c++, математика

Задача:
 Для положительного целого числа n определим функцию `f`:

```
f(n) =  - 1 + 2 - 3 + .. + ( - 1)^n*n
```

Посчитать `f(n)` для данного целого числа n.

Написал сначала через `for` превысил лимит времени:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum(0), n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i(1); i <= n; ++i)
        sum += pow(-1, i)*i;
    cout << sum;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Затем с рекурсией превысило ограничение по памяти:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int n, sum(0), i(1);

void rek()
{
    while (i <= n)
    {
        sum += pow(-1, i)*i;
        ++i;
        rek();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    rek();
    cout << sum;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите оптимизировать код (на тесте n = 1000000000).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А просто подумать? Что каждая *пара* дает число 1?

Так что в результате получается

```
(-1 + (-1)^n + 2*n*(-1)^n)/4
```

Ну, а код

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << ((2*n+1)*((n%2) ? -1 : 1) - 1)/4 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, опыта маловато еще у меня. Не всегда понимаю что делать.

Comment: Главное ускорение программы - за счет алгоритма. Как бы вы ни считали свой ряд (кстати, не используйте для таких мелочей `pow` - зачем? когда достаточно просто знак поменять у переменной...), пока это ряд - это O(n), здесь же - O(1).

Comment: Если не получается самостоятельно - вот, можно обратиться к этому ресурсу - см. [тут](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+i*%28-1%29^i,+i,+1,+n)

Comment: А вольфрам знаю. Просто охото самому писать алгоритмы) Чтоб опыта набираться